# TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable with zip()

Tags: python, list-comprehension

the question goes like this:

```
revenue = [30000, 50000, 70000, 90000]
cost = [10000, 15000, 20000, 30000]
```

Write a comprehension together with the zip() function to make a new list that maintains profits.

I tried doing it with for-loop:

```
new_list = []
for revenue, cost in zip(revenue, cost):
    profit = revenue - cost
    new_list.append(profit)

new_list
```

output:

```
[20000, 35000, 50000, 60000]
```

which is my desired output, but I cannot do it this way as I must use comprehension.

So, when I tried coding it with comprehension:

```
zipped_list = list(zip(revenue, cost))
[revenue - cost for num1, num2 in zipped_list]
```

I get the error message of:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable.
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: The actual error produced by this code is `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'list'`, because you've simply typoed the variables you want to subtract. If you're running your two code samples after each other, then yeah, you've replaced the `revenue` and  `cost` variables with ints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the work:

```
revenue = [30000, 50000, 70000, 90000]
cost = [10000, 15000, 20000, 30000]
output = [rev - cost for rev, cost in zip(revenue, cost)]
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
[20000, 35000, 50000, 60000]
```